# Package Dependency issue with git Requires: libcurl.so.3 on CEntOS

Tags: git, centos, libcurl

I 'm trying to install git on CEntOS 6. I use command `yum install git`

It Gives Error with dependency require libcurl.so(3).  Installed libcurl.so(4)

Comment: I know it should be obvious but you should always clearly specify your question and if possible add more details.

Answer (score 1):

I found the fault.. Issues with YUM repository versions...

There was issue with my Yum repository.

I was using the X86_64 OS and my YUM EPEL Repository was of 32bit Architecture.

Just uninstalled the 32bit EPEL repo and installed 64bit EPEL repo.

It now works fine.